# collectAsList in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any specific reason for `collectAsList` method of Spark DataFrame API to return a `java.util.List` instead of a Scala List?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on this choice so it's up to inference I guess. I would assume it's because `java.util.List` is mutable whereas the scala `List` is not (and perhaps the use case here is better for a mutable list).

Comment: No specific reason! http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MutableList is a mutable scala list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its mostly a convenience function for Java users and also makes things much simpler for the Python API. Looking at the git logs (and also the since annotation) it was introduced in the initial merge of the DataFrame API so it wasn't necessarily added in response to a particular need. Sometimes some of the APIs return Java types since they are easier to interface with in Python (through py4j) - but that doesn't appear to be the case here (the python API collects by turning the DF into an RDD and collecting on the RDD).